# Powershell, Get-MailboxPermission returns permissions, but can't change it with Remove-MailboxPermission

Tags: powershell, office365

I try to give/remove access to the shared mailbox on Office 365 via powershell. I came to point, where my connector to O365 works, and I can list users of shared mailbox with below code, and this works fine, it list users and it's permissions to mailbox.

```
Get-MailboxPermission -Identity $MailboxName
```

But then, I want to add full access permission to this mailbox with Add-MailboxPermission, and "The operation couldn't be performed because object 'User' couldn't be found on 'domain'" appears. But, when I list permissions, the user is present.

```
Add-MailboxPermission -Identity "$MailboxName" -User "$AddUser" -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All -AutoMapping $false
```

I also tried with Get-RecipientPermission, but it also doesn't work.
Did someone come accross something like that, and figured it out?

Comment: Pipe them together: `Get-MailboxPermission -Identity $MailboxName | Add-MailboxPermission -User "$AddUser" -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All -AutoMapping $false `

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I managed to resolve it. 
Thanks everyone for help.
I realised, that my if condition Was wrong, thus it always resulted in object not found and not adding user to account (eventhough Add-MailboxPermission was correct, the script stopped before executing it).